# Solving $\partial_tu-\Delta u+\vec{V}\cdot\nabla u=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How can I solve the equation $\partial_tu-\Delta u+\vec{V}\cdot\nabla u=0,$ where $\vec{V}$ is a constant vector, for a given initial condition $u_0$? The only method I'm really aware of is the method of characteristic curves, which led nowhere.

Comment: It'd seem that $V$ is a vector field and that the period in the above is intended as a dot product. This should be stated explicitly in the question, especially since it's not stated whether $V$ is a function of $t,\vec{x}$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, $V$ is a constant vector, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: let $u(x,t)=v(x-t\,V,t)$  and obtain an equation for $v$.

Comment: Along similar lines, one can make the substitution $\vec{x}'=\vec{x}-t \vec{V}$ and transform the PDE accordingly.

Comment: How could I have guessed this particular form?

Comment: Because the term $V\cdot \nabla u$ represents a convection in the direction of the vector $V$. Compare with the first order equation $u_t+u_x=0$, or in more dimensions $u_t+V\cdot \nabla u=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Separation of Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), the idea is, if you assume $u({\bf r}, t) = X({\bf r})T(t)$, then the equation can be rewritten as

$$
\frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{{\rm d}T}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{1}{X({\bf r})}[\Delta X({\bf r}) - V\cdot \nabla X({\bf r})]
$$

So you have something on the l.h.s that depends only on $t$, and on the r.h.s something that depends solely on ${\bf r}$, so these two things must be a constant, $\alpha$. Therefore, you're left with two separated differential equations

$$
\frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{{\rm d}T}{{\rm d}t} = \alpha ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \frac{1}{X({\bf r})}[\Delta X({\bf r}) - V\cdot \nabla X({\bf r})] = \alpha
$$

You can apply the same argument to try and separate the last one again, depending on the geometry of the domain you have at hand

Answer (score 0):

Do the Fourier transform of the equation 
$$u(r, t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{u}(t, q)e^{ir\cdot{q}}d^{n}q$$
To give
$$\partial_{t}\hat{u}(t, q)=-(|q|^{2}+iq\cdot{V})\hat{u}(t, q)$$
The solution is
$$\hat{u}(t, q)=ce^{-|q|^{2}t}e^{-iq\cdot{V}t}$$
Take the Fourier transform of the initial condition
$$\hat{u}_{0}(q)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}u_{0}(r)e^{-ir\cdot{q}}d^{n}r$$
Then
$$c=\hat{u}_{0}(q)$$
And the solution is
$$u(r, t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{u}_{0}(q)e^{-|q|^{2}t}e^{iq\cdot(r-Vt)}d^{n}q$$
For example, if $u_{0}(r)=u_{0}\delta^{(n)}(r-r')$ and $n=1$
then
$$\hat{u}_{0}(q)=u_{0}e^{-ir'\cdot{q}}$$
and
$$u(r, t)=u_{0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-q^{2}t+iq([r-r']-Vt)}dq=u_{0}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}\exp\Big(-\frac{([r-r']-Vt)^{2}}{4t}\Big)$$